# Prove $\,\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{4n+1}{n}}=2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

As shown in the title, I'm asked to prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}}=2$ using the $\epsilon,N$ definition only.
My solution was completely different from the solution they posted so I want to know if I did something wrong.
Let $\epsilon>0$, we have to find $N$ s.t $\forall n>N$. $\left|\sqrt{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}}-2\right|<\epsilon$. Since $n$ is iterating over naturals, we can say that $\sqrt{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}}-2$ is always positive by plugging in the minimum of $\mathbb{N}$.

I continued by multiplying by $\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}}+2\right)$.\
$\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}}-2\right)\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}}+2\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}}+2\right)}= \dfrac{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}-4}{\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}}+2\right)}\stackrel{(*)}{<}\dfrac{1}{n}$
while (*) was using the previous conclusion that the denominator is always positive and greater than $1$.

Now I can say that we can take $N=\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}+10$ and this satisfies the desired.

Comment: I think the identity $\frac{4n+1}{n} = 4 + \frac{1}{n}$ makes (*) a lot more obvious.

Comment: "Since $n$ is iterating over naturals, we can say that $\sqrt{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}}-2$ is always positive by plugging in the minimum of $\mathbb{N}$." I don't get this. I think you should clarify what you mean here.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I wanted to show that we can get rid of the absolute value because the least value n can get is $1$ and plugging $1$ yields $\frac{5}{2}-2>0$ but I forgot the square root, I think you just pointed out where I fell, Thanks!

Comment: If your sequence is increasing for all $n$, @Fairuz_, then you can confirm that the difference of the first term and the limit is positive and conclude that so must all the others.  That's true whether or not you have a square root.  If it's not increasing, though...

Comment: "s always positive by plugging in the minimum of N."  How do you know it will still be positive for larger values of $n$?  Did you show it was increasing?

Comment: You are stating a lot of things without verification.  Why assume $\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}}+2\right)$ is greater than $1$?  Why assume $\dfrac{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}-4}{\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}}+2\right)}$ is less than $\frac 1n$? You are, of course, correct in these assumptions but you have no more reason to state them without verification than to simply state the limit is $2$ because it obviously is.

Comment: Otherwise I guess it works.  You can say that $\frac {4n+1}{n} > 4$ so $|...|$ is always positve.  And you can show that $\dfrac{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}-4}{\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{4n+1}{n}}+2\right)}< \frac {\frac {4n+1}n - 4}{3} < \frac {4n+1}n - 4=4 + \frac 1n -4 = \frac 1n$ and you'd be done and that would be correct.  But it is rather roundabout.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would have taken a somewhat different approach, because I prefer to avoid square roots, when possible.  The first question that I would have asked myself is: given a small positive $~\epsilon,~$ how large does $~n~$ have to be so that $~4 + 1/n < (2 + \epsilon)^2.~$  Note that it is sufficient for $~4 + 1/n < 4 + 4\epsilon < (2 + \epsilon)^2.~$

Comment: @Fairuz_ , you could take $\,\color{#0000FF}{N=\dfrac1\varepsilon}\,$ instead of $\,\color{#FF6200}{N=\dfrac1\varepsilon+10}\,$
and it would satisfy the desired result too.

Comment: @Fairuz_ , what do you think about my approach? Look at my answer and tell me if you like it.

Answer (score 2):

An idea:

$$\frac{4n+1}n-4=\frac1n\implies\left|\frac{4n+1}n-4\right|=\left|\frac1n\right|=\frac1n$$

You can already from here deduce $\;\frac{4n+1}n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}4\;$ by means of a $\;\delta,\epsilon\;$ argument or however, and

since the sequence is clearly positive all the time, we get

$$\sqrt{\frac{4n+1}n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\sqrt4=2$$

Or else:

$$\left|\sqrt{\frac{4n+1}n}-2\right|=\left|{\frac{\sqrt{4n+1}}{\sqrt n}}-\sqrt 4\right|=\left|\frac{\sqrt{4n+1}-\sqrt{4n}}n\right|=\left|\frac1{n\left(\sqrt{4n+1}+\sqrt{4n}\right)}\right|\le$$

$$\le\frac1{2n\sqrt{4n}}=\frac1{4n^{3/2}}$$

and again: a $\;\delta,\epsilon\;$ argument or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks fine. Only problem is your reasoning why we can leave out absolute value. $\sqrt{\frac{4n+1}{n}}-2$ has no minimum value. It's easier to see in form $\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{n}}-2$ where $\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{n+1}}-2$ is a smaller number. My approach to show that the sequence is positive for all n would be: $2=\sqrt{4}<\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{n}}$ (because $\frac{1}{n}>0$)$\iff0<\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{n}}-2$.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that it might be instructive to present a more streamlined approach. To that end we proceed.

First, we can write the sequence of interest as

$$\sqrt{\frac{4n+1}{n}}=2\sqrt{1+\frac1{4n}}\tag1$$

Second, we observe that

$$1<\sqrt{1+\frac1{4n}}\le 1+\frac1{8n}\tag2$$

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ together reveals the estimates

$$2<\sqrt{\frac{4n+1}{n}}<2+\frac1{4n}$$

which imply that

$$0<\sqrt{\frac{4n+1}{n}}-2<\frac1{4n}\tag 3$$

And now, from $(3)$, for any $\varepsilon>0$, $\left|\sqrt{\frac{4n+1}{n}}-2\right|<\varepsilon$ whenever $n>\frac1{4\varepsilon}$.  And we are done!

Comment: @mathstudent101 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

**My approach.**

For any $\,\varepsilon>0\,$ there exists $\,N_{\varepsilon}=\left\lfloor\dfrac1{\varepsilon(\varepsilon+4)}\right\rfloor+1\in\Bbb N\,$ such that for any $\,n>N_{\varepsilon}\,$ it results that

$\left|\sqrt{\dfrac{4n+1}n}-2\right|=\left|\sqrt{4+\dfrac1n}-2\right|=\sqrt{4+\dfrac1n}-2<$

$<\sqrt{4\!+\!\dfrac1{N_{\varepsilon}}}-2=\!\sqrt{4\!+\!\dfrac1{\left\lfloor\!\frac1{\varepsilon(\varepsilon+4)}\!\right\rfloor\!+\!1}}-2\!\!\!\underset{\overbrace{\text{ because }\left\lfloor\!\frac1{\varepsilon(\varepsilon+4)}\!\right\rfloor+1>\frac1{\varepsilon(\varepsilon+4)}}}{<}$

$<\sqrt{4+\dfrac1{\frac1{\varepsilon(\varepsilon+4)}}}-2=\sqrt{4+\varepsilon\big(\varepsilon\!+\!4\big)}-2=$

$=\sqrt{\varepsilon^2+4\epsilon+4}-2=\sqrt{\big(\varepsilon+2\big)^{\!2}}-2=\varepsilon\,.$